# Shouldn't we all get presents on Meta's birthday?

Tags: feature-request, badges, meta, badge-request

You know, like the way hobbits celebrate their birthdays?  I know that Meta graciously posted a URI to waffles on Google Images, but how about something more substantial like a few rep points or a special one time only badge?

Comment: Yes! A one time only gift of rep every year! Like those free gifts I have to pay for! Or a Happy Coincidence Badge!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What, yours hasn't arrived yet? I got mine in the mail this morning and it is fantastic. I can't stop using it. It takes a lot of effort just to stop fiddling with it long enough to type this post.

Anyone else get theirs?

First, I can't believe how easy it is to use and how fun it is. Second, it's great how it integrates with Stack Overflow so well no matter where I am or how I'm using it.

Fortunately its battery lasts 48 hours without a recharge. I know what I won't be doing tonight: sleeping!

Let's all post pictures of ours when we get them. Mine's blue. What colour is yours?

Evidently mine was the first to arrive, so I won't gloat about it. Just know that it is the best thing ever and Jeff is a really cool guy to have sent them out to the top Meta users for its birthday. Thanks again, man.

Comment: I just got mine! Perhaps you need 10k rep to get it... all I know is: "It's AWESOME!"

Comment: @Juan: Isn't it great? It's unbelievable! What colour is yours?

Comment: It's blue also, I don't know if it comes in other colors; let's wait to see what color the others get

Comment: Mine glows.  It came last night.

Comment: @Squilly: Ooooooh.

Comment: I got mine too.  I'm going to sell it on craigslist now!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the top of the page.  We all got [**waffles**](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=waffles).

Mmmmm.  Waffles.

(As long as they're not cooked on [**this**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37493/what-do-stack-overflow-users-like-for-breakfast/37522#37522).)

Comment: What?  Did someone say "let's [GoogleImagesBomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlebomb) the word 'waffles'"?  I could have sworn I heard someone say "let's GoogleImagesBomb the word 'waffles' with photos of unicorns."

Answer (score 2):

People who were around since Meta's beginning can finally earn the Yearling badge. That's a present, aye?

Comment: I was quite surprised on Monday when I got the badge. Time flies when you're having fun. (And as one frog said to the other, time's fun when you're having flies.)

Comment: @mmyers Time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.

Comment: Hey, I do believe today is Bad Joke Day!

Comment: I'm so using that in the future.

Comment: So actually its birthday was celebrated a bit too late, or the yearling badges were handed out too early?

Answer (score 2):

Happy second birthday, meta. :)

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/

[image: happy birthday meta]

Comment: yay! e-cards for everybody...wait, e-cards?

Answer (score 0):

It's meta's birthday **and** it's friday, what more can we ask for?

Comment: ...I'm utterly amazed that it isn't until 10:00AM EST that I realize that today is actually Friday...